# Como puedo enviar el nombre de mi clase como parámetro a un método e instanciarlo o crear uno nuevo ahí

Tags: java, netbeans, class, constructor

Pido ayuda para poder resolver, como pasar mi clase que contiene `getter` y `setter` a un método como parámetro y desde el método poder crear el nuevo objeto. Esta clase que tengo llena un JCombobox con query de la base de datos. aqui pongo mi metodo al que le envio los datos.

```
public void LlenaComboBoxMysq(JComboBox<String> combocli, String sql, int columna, int columna2,String lista) {
        
        try {
DefaultComboBoxModel value = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            cn = Conexion.getConnection();
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            combocli.removeAllItems();
                         
                    while (rs.next()) {
                                         
                        value.addElement(new claseOriginal(rs.getInt(columna)));
                      
              --CAMBIARLO POR ALGO ASI---
                        value.addElement(new claseEnviadaPorParametro (rs.getInt(columna)));

                    }
               
                            
            }

            combocli.setModel(value);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo objeto Class cuenta con la opcion de crear una instancia, puedes llamar directamente a

```
clase.newInstance();
```

Pero es una forma ya obsoleta, la manera actual de hacerlo es

```
clase.getDeclaredConstructor(tiposDeParametros).newInstance(parametros);
```

por lo que tu metodo quedaria:

```
private void metodoCrearNew(Class clase) {
    try {
        Class[] tiposDeParametros = new Class[1];
        tiposDeParametros[0] = String.class;
        Object instance = clase.getDeclaredConstructor(tiposDeParametros).newInstance("Hello world");
        System.out.println(instance);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewBeanForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Y el metodo para llamarla seria algo como

```
private void formItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                      
    System.out.println("changed item state");
    String selectedItem = (String)this.getSelectedItem();
    switch (selectedItem) {
        case "claseConGetterYSetter":
            metodoCrearNew(ClaseConGetterSetter.class);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("String selected");
    }
}
```

Y la salida de la ejecucion daria:

```
changed item state
String selected
changed item state
String selected
changed item state
ClaseConGetterSetter(aString=Hello world)
changed item state
ClaseConGetterSetter(aString=Hello world)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, solo que no he podido ver la manera de implementarlos a mi código, ya que en el mismo método, inserto datos de mi base de datos a el jcombobox, de echo actualice mi pregunta, por que era la primera vez que usaba este comunidad para hacer esta consulta. ¿habrá manera de que me puedas ayudar? te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: si, la manera es que hagas otra pregunta por cada problema en especifico que se te vaya presentando